# Prove that $\|u-v\|/\|w-u\| \neq (\|u\|-\|v\|)/(\|w\|-\|u\|)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m studying advanced linear algebra right now, and need help on the following question:

> Suppose there are three vectors $u$, $v$ and $w \in \mathbb R^m$, prove $$\frac{\|u-v\|_2}{\|w-u\|_2} \neq \frac{\|u\|_2-\|v\|_2}{\|w\|_2-\|u\|_2}.$$

My guess is to use a counterexample. The commonly used special cases are “when vectors are parallel” or “when vectors are orthogonal”, but I tried both and got stuck in the middle. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Obviously it is in general not equal f.e. with $u=1, v=w=0$ because $1 \neq -1$

Comment: Well, they sometimes are equal. And sometimes the right side isn't defined when the left side is.

Comment: But it is certainly true that there will always be  $u,v,w$ where both sides are defined and not equal.

Comment: For example, take $u\neq 0, v=-u$ and $w=2u.$